# Do communicating vessels work when water is moving?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, vortex

I want to know if the water level equalize in communicating vessels, when in one of the vessels there is a vortex, or any other water movement, and if the level does equalize, what will be the level?

I made a simple drawing:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They will equalize pressure at the entrance to the tube between them. That pressure is the density of the fluid times the height from the bottom to the lowest point in the vortex, because the fluid at the lowest point has zero velocity and so is equivalent to standing fluid.

Comment: And that means that the water level in the other level will decrease right?

Comment: Right. The level in one should equal the bottom level in the other, assuming the tube is directly under the center of the vortex. If it's off-center, I'm not sure.